# How can I iterate over a MeshGrid?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have a function that returns the density estimate for points (x, y). I would like to iterate over all (x, y) points for a given 2-D grid and have the density function compute the estimate for each point so that I can have a matrix of density values which I can then plot.

Say the function is called `density(x, y)`, that takes any point (x, y) and returns the density estimate (z) for that (x, y). I would like to be able to apply the function to each point within a 2-Dimensional grid and store the density estimate wherein I could use, say, `plt.pcolormesh()` to view the density.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear to me what you want to do. Sounds like you want to interpolate a function? Maybe show your "function that returns a density estimate". I assume you know `for` loops? If its not interpolation, maybe what you want is `meshgrid` and vectorization?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome. I have edited the question and I hope it makes more sense now. I am fairly new to StackOverflow and am still trying to get the hang of the manner in which questions are asked so please excuse any lapses in my questions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something on the lines of this.

First, define a density function. For simplicity, I am taking the function `|x| + |y|`.

```py
def density(x, y):
    return np.abs(x) + np.abs(y)
```

Now let's define the points along `x` and `y` dimensions and populate the arrays. In the following example, `x` and `y` are 1D arrays which store `n_x` and `n_y` points each sampled uniformly in `[-1, 1]`.

```
n_x = 100
n_y = 100
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, n_x)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, n_y)
```

Compute the grid in terms of pairs of points and compute the density `D` over each point in the grid.

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
D = density(xx, yy)
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly iterate over meshgrid, you can use the seemingly scalar `density()` function for the arrays `xx` and `yy` as well. For details about `meshgrid`, see this [page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

Next simply use `pcolormesh()` to display or save.

```
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, D)
plt.title('Density function = |x| + |y|')
plt.savefig('density.png')
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Tip: try `np.vectorize` if your function does not accept array arguments like in the example below.